# SugarCRM экспорт в Excel

Tags: php, linux, config, configuration

Есть SugarCRM и в ней необходимо экспортировать данные в Excel/Calc. Нашел, что она умеет экспортировать сама в .csv, что подойдет. Но при выборе данных для экспорта и нажатии кнопы "Экспортировать" появляется страница с содержимым "Экспорт выключен.".
При этом в конфиге все параметры говорят о том, что экспорт включен.
Подскажите, как его включить, если он все же выключен? И как экспортировать данные, если дело не в настройках?

Comment: Нашел! Кроме config.php есть еще config_override.php в котором есть строка ...admin_export_only'] = true, заменил на false и все заработало.

Comment: Интересно  не генерируется ли config_override.php на лету из каких-то дополнительных конфигов =\